# Multiple Dashboard widget instances don't survive widget update. Any way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, macos, dashcode, mac-dashboard-widget

I've written a Mac OS X Dashboard to show the StackOverflow flair of yourself and other people.

My problem is that whenever I update that widget to a new version, all previous instances are removed and a single new instance is created on the Dashboard. So if you previously followed the flair of 4 people you'll have to recreate the widgets and enter their user-IDs again. :(

Is there any way to keep all running instances while updating a widget?

Checking the preferences file, I see that a new instance is created after a new version of the widget is deployed. Is this by design? Does **all** widgets work like this, by any chance?? If so, can this be manually circumvented somehow?

You can find the widget in question, including the project files, at http://widget.huxhorn.de

I've changed the code in remove() to **set** the preferences to the correct values instead of *null* as suggested below - but this doesn't help, either.
What's my mistake?? Help! I'm stuck!

---

The other problem of my widget has been fixed:
I accidentally called

```
widget.preferenceForKey(null, dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey));
```

instead of

```
widget.preferenceForKey(dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey));
```

but this is now fixed (not yet released).

Answer (score 1):

I know about this tool that takes over the install process: http://junecloud.com/software/mac/smart-widget-installer.html

[image]
<sub>(source: [junecloud.com](http://junecloud.com/images/entries/.junecode/480x800/20080928_7125.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think your calls to setPreferenceForKey and preferenceForKey look strange. Where does that `null` come from. Shouldn't they look like

```
widget.preferenceForKey(dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey))
widget.setPreferenceForKey(value, dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey));
```

Does the syntax with `null`

```
widget.setPreferenceForKey(null, dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey))
```

in `remove()` delete the preference? That would explain you situation I guess. On Update the `remove()` gets surley called and thus on restart of the widget the preferences are gone.

---

I guess there is only one way to keep your preferences during an update. Create one preferencekey without relying on dashboard.createInstancePreferenceKey but instead think yourself of a unique key value.

In this preferenceKey you could then save all ever entered userids (by any instance) with a growing (say comma seperated) list. When a widget instance is opened an the `widget.preferenceForKey(dashcode.createInstancePreferenceKey(userIdPrefKey))` isn't already set you could let the user choose one of those by giving him a select or such a thing

I was just thinking maybe the update process is nice enough to migrate the preferences to the new verison. Even when you don't remove the preferences I think the widget.identifier (createInstancePreferenceKey) will have changed an thus you can't access the "old" settings.

Comment: Good idea, I tried that and changed the code to - again - set the preferences to the correct values... does not help :( That code was originally meant to clean up after the widget so that there wouldn't be any unused prefs left from removed widget instances...

Comment: Setting the values to null was ok. A single new instance is created in case of an update so removing the values of previous instances is the way to go, I guess.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Proposed another solution in modified answer

Comment: I've just created a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027240/is-it-possible-to-create-new-widget-instances-from-within-a-dashboard-widget

I think that this would be necessary to be able to keep/restore previous instances. Thanks for staying with me on that topic.