# Where are Dashboard Widget preferences actually saved?

Tags: javascript, macos, widget, dashboard, dashcode

This is a followup question to my other [widget-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023397/dashboard-widget-is-reset-in-case-of-a-new-version-any-way-to-prevent-this).
I'd like to check what's actually written into the preferences of the widget. Where is that data actually stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preferences for each individual widget and the dashboard itself are saved in the folder /Users/YOUR-USER-NAME/Library/Preferences/.

Comment: Thanks! For reference: widget prefs are stored in files named widget-<widget-identifier>.plist in that directory.